# HTML video file not playing in IE 11

Tags: html, video

I received a video that I need to add to my website. I used a program, Easy HTML5 video to encode the video for my website.

When the video finishes encoding and saving, the video opens in IE using the local PC address c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\videos\video1.html and plays fine.

I then upload the video to my site and IE tells me "invalid source". I tried the video from my website via Firefox and it plays fine.

I thought it had to do with the mime settings on my server, but I verified that

```
fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"
fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"
fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"
```

were correctly added to IIS. Does anyone know if this is an issue with IE 11, or might there be more mime types I need to add?

Comment: Without seeing the code of how you load the video and display it, it's difficult to determine the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened. After posting the question I deleted all the videos and waited for a reply. when I got one I recreated the video to test and now it's working. All is good. Maybe I missed a step. Most likely, I'm thinking that the video might not have uploaded because Dreamweaver couldn't upload the video file since it was open in IE.